# How to add breakpoint at runtime when debugging Golang using VSCode?

Tags: debugging, go, visual-studio-code, delve

After activating a debug session, the program started running. At this time, I tried to create a breakpoint. Unfortunately, it said "Unverified Breakpoint" and the color turned into dark black, different from the other pre-defined one (which was red). You can see more clearly on the image below. The debugger would never stop at the line of the breakpoint.

Did I miss any steps?

[image]

Comment: Perhaps its related to issue: [`#360`](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-go/issues/360) or [`#941`](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-go/issues/941).

Comment: @putu thanks but the issues are different from this